# iOS: Constraint in a custom tableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview, constraints, autolayout

I have a tableview with a custom cell, where inside it I have a textview.
For this cell I determinate its hight with the size of text and it's ok.

I work in autolayout, so for my cell I use two constraints to expand the textview for all space cell in this way

[image]

I can say that it work fine and my textview expand itself for all cell space.

In the view controller I have a control to check when the text (the string) is empty. When it is empty I return 0 for the cell hight.

But in this case when I return 0 and text_view is empty I have a crash but I don't know how to solve.

this is the message

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1704864a0 V:|-(25)-[UITextView:0x15454d960]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x178179680 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1704864f0 V:[UITextView:0x15454d960]-(23)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x178179680 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x17889a220 h=--& v=--& V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x178179680(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1704864f0 V:[UITextView:0x15454d960]-(23)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x178179680 )>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: Why are you including the row if it has no content?

Comment: Try setting `[self.contentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];` in custom cell.

Comment: Setting view's alpha to 0 is much better way to hide views.

Comment: I don't change number of row because I have often 7 rows, all different. And it's easy hide the row that has not data, but now I solved with '[cell.contentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];' thanks to @Akhilrajtr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` of cell contentView by,

```
[self.contentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```